Blazor EditForm and jquery datepicker
I am currently trying Blazor on a new project. I want a Blazor Form EditForm with a jquery datepicker in it.
The problem is that form the EditForm to get the value of the datepicker, I think it needs to be an InputDate. But if I use an input date, I can't use jQuery to make it look good and still work with EditForm bindings.
Here is the simplified form :
<EditForm id="openReportForm" Model="Model" FormName="openReportForm" OnValidSubmit="OpenReport">
  <p>
    <span class="green">Date :</span><br />
    <span>Du :</span><input type="button" id="prevDayBtn" value="<">
    <InputText id="datepicker" class="oa-datepicker" @bind-Value="Model.SelectedDateTimeStr" />
    <!--<input type="text" id="datepicker" class="oa-datepicker" @bind-value="Model.SelectedDateTime">-->
    <input type="button" id="nextDayBtn" value=">">
  </p>

  <br /><br />
  <button id="btnDisplayReport" type="submit" class="btn oa-ui-button">Afficher</button>
</EditForm>

Here is the current code to design the datepicker with jQuery:
function configureDatepicker(datepickerName, fieldName) {
  $(datepickerName).datepicker({
    dateFormat: "DD, d MM yy",
    showAnim: "slideDown",
    showOtherMonths: true,
    selectOtherMonths: true,
    showButtonPanel: true,
    changeMonth: true,
    changeYear: true,
    maxDate: "+0D",
    onClose: function (dateText, inst) {
      var date = $(this).datepicker('getDate');
      // Mettez à jour la valeur du champ de modèle C# lorsque l'utilisateur sélectionne une nouvelle date
      $(fieldName).val(date.toISOString().split('T')[0]);
      // Sauvegardez la date sélectionnée dans le localStorage
      sessionStorage.setItem(datepickerName, date.getTime());
    },
    onSelect: function (dateText, inst) {
      var date = $(this).datepicker('getDate');
      // Mettez à jour la valeur du champ de modèle C# lorsque l'utilisateur sélectionne une nouvelle date
      $(fieldName).val(date.toISOString().split('T')[0]);
      // Sauvegardez la date sélectionnée dans le localStorage
      sessionStorage.setItem(datepickerName, date.getTime());
    }
  });
}

Note that in the end, it will be more than one datepicker with different configurations.
How can I make the binding and jQuery work properly?

I think its its just about the looks then it can be achieved one way or the other but its tough to say what would work , so could you perhaps create a reproducible code on https://jsfiddle.net/ or https://stackblitz.com/

may I understand your requirement as, using jquery datepicker in blazor component and make sure the datepicker worked like when we use Blazor InputDate while the input itself has jquery UI style which making it looks good?

Why don't you use native Blazor controls?

I found a blog here, could you pls help check whether it solved your issue or not? https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/5290232/Blazor-datepicker-Component-using-JQuery

@TinyWang yes, exactly!
This blog post seems to me way too complicated to do the job !
I was wondering maybe, I should use a jquerydatepicker and with some js copy it's value in a hidden InputDate fiels so the value is transmitte correctly to the form submit.
What do you think?

Ok, I found my own solution by keeping a datepicker with jquery then add a InputDate hidden. Then with a bit of JS, I synched have synched then using onClose and onSelect event of datepicker.
